# I have a set of string data that I want plot in desired partitions with the string neatly near the plotted circles

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

```
var svgcanvas = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", 725)
.attr("height", 500);
```

A sample of my data set which will be pulled from a DB

```
var jsoncirclehigh =[

                        { 
                            "blah":"Javascript",
                            "blah":"",
                            "blah":"",

                        },
                            {

                                "Technology": "D3",
                                "TechField":"",
                                "Devphase":"",

                            }, 
                    ];
```

The Shape that I forgot to add

```
 svgcanvas.append("svg:path")
    .attr("d","M -200,0 A200,200 0 0,0 500,0 L -200,0") 
    .attr("transform", "translate(220,400) scale(1, -1)")
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("fill", "yellow");
```

Circles that I created which I would like to match up with the data

```
  svgcanvas.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr("cx", 200)
    .attr("cy", 250)
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
    .on("mouseout", function() {d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");})
    .text(function(d) {return d;});
```

Tried to match the text with the circles but did not work

```
                         svgcanvas.selectAll("text")
                                    .data(jsoncirclehigh)
                                    .enter()
                                    .append("text")
                                    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                                    .attr("font-size", "11px")
                                    .attr("fill", "red");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your circles and `jsoncirclehigh` would be in the same data structure. The point of d3.js is to use data (like `jsoncirclehigh`) to drive the creation of SVG elements. Try something more like:

```
var svgcanvas = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

var jsoncirclehigh = [
                       {cx:100, cy: 100, r: 2.5,
                        label:"technology"},
                       {cx:200, cy: 200, r: 2.5,
                        label:"rocks"}
                     ];

svgcanvas.selectAll("circle")
         .data(jsoncirclehigh)
         .enter().append("circle")
           .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
           .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
           .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; })
           .style("stroke", "steelblue")
           .style("fill", "blue");

svgcanvas.selectAll("text")
       .data(jsoncirclehigh)
       .enter().append("svg:text")
        .text(function(d) { return d.label; })
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.cx + 10; })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.cy + 10; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2jw9k/4/

Comment: Would you possibly know how to restrict these circles within a shape?

Comment: @user1701622 You're welcome! Re: follow-up Q -- come again? Like only plot them if their center coordinates are within some polygon?

Comment: As in eventually I want the data entries to be dynamic on update etc. Therefore, I would like to restrict the circles so they do not go beyond the shape.

Comment: @user1701622 I'm still not clear. "Beyond the shape" -- what shape? The SVG container element? I'm not following how that relates to an update event.

Comment: My fault, I forgot to include it - can you see it now? Essentially I would like to update & edit the data without going back to the hard code. I possibly thought I should create a form? So, yes nothing to do with restriction, that is a separate question.